# Error undefined methode 'interger' when make migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, migration

### I'm building a database with Ruby, but when I tried to make a model (database table) a couple errors showed up, and I don't understand what is " in block in change" and "change". Here's the error.

```
>C:\Users\MINH\Monika>rake db:migrate
>== 20161130153857 CreatePages: migrating ======================================
>-- create_table(:pages)
>rake aborted!
>StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

>undefined method `interger' for #><ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::TableDefinition:0x58a4528>
>C:/Users/MINH/Monika/db/migrate/20161130153857_create_pages.rb:11:in `block in >change'
>C:/Users/MINH/Monika/db/migrate/20161130153857_create_pages.rb:3:in `change'
>NoMethodError: undefined method `interger' for #>>>..<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::TableDefinition:0x58a4528>
>C:/Users/MINH/Monika/db/migrate/20161130153857_create_pages.rb:11:in `block in >change'
>C:/Users/MINH/Monika/db/migrate/20161130153857_create_pages.rb:3:in `change'
>Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
>(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

---

This is the migration

```
>class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
>  def change
>    create_table :pages do |t|
>      t.string :name
>      t.text :description
>      t.text :address
>      t.text :contact
>      t.string :profile_image
>      t.string :cover_image
>      t.string :look_book
>      t.interger :seller_id
>
>     t.timestamps 
>    end
>  end
>end
```

Comment: You mean `integer`?

Comment: Ah i know, i forgot.

Comment: hahahaah.....check seller_id bro it's 'integer' not 'interger'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this:**

```
   class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
      def change
        create_table :pages do |t|
          t.string :name
          t.text :description
          t.text :address
          t.text :contact
          t.string :profile_image
          t.string :cover_image
          t.string :look_book
          t.integer :seller_id 

          t.timestamps
        end
      end
    end
```